# HTML Video BG as cover but with content

Tags: html, css, video

I would like to create a subpage on my website with a full video as header. So the video should be 100% width of the browser and 100% height of the view (what the user sees without scrolling).

Directly underneath is normal content with a white background in position: relative. The user can scroll through the whole page!

1. How can I implement, that the video acts like background-cover? Exact size (100% width and 100%height of the view) without displaying the rest of the video OR stretching the video.
2. How can I implement it that the content part is directly seamlessly under the video without direct px inputs? So a user with a smaller screen has the same space between the video and the content.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You'd need to relax the stretching requirement for a start. Mathematically, if the user's browser is wider or taller than the video, it would have to stretch to some extent. What do you mean by "displaying the rest of the video"?

Comment: By "displaying the rest of the video" I mean, when I scroll to the bottom, that the rest-height of the video is being displayed.